# Test node.js RESTful API without express

Tags: node.js

I have an endpoints that I want to test. My endpoint is not written in express. How can I test it?

My endpoint:

```
const http = require('http');

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    if (req.url == '/xyz' && req.method === 'GET') {
        //process
    }
    res.end();
}).listen(port, hostname, () => {
    console.log(`Server running on port ${port}`);
});

module.exports = { server: server };
```

Comment: What kind of test? Are you talking about automated testing? Or maybe you can just open it up in a browser?

Comment: I added it in the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `chai-http`. It works without express.js flawlessly.

```
const chai_ = require('chai');
const chaiHttp = require('chai-http');
const server= require('../../src/main');

chai_.use(chaiHttp);

describe('Health check', () => {
    it('responds with HTTP 200', (done) => {
        return chai_.request(server)
            .get('/xyz')
            .end( (err, res) => {
                chai_.expect(err).to.be.null;
                chai_.expect(res).to.have.status(200);
                done();
            });
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Run the code to start the http server at the beginning of your tests and then use a standard http client to invoke your code. Optionally, separate your code from the http code into a form it can be invoked directly and test against those definitions instead.

Ex.

```
function createObjectInDatabase() {
  return createObject();
}
```

...

```
if (req.url == '/object' && req.method === 'POST') {
        return res.send(createObjectInDatabase());
}
```